# Qt5 and QML: How to update QQuickPaintedItem after widget resize?

Tags: image, resize, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'll be very appreciated for help!

i created a custom object, inherited from QQuickPaintedItem and send it to QML application.

It goes well, but there is some issue.

I need to repaint scaled image every time widget changes it's own size. 
But i can't get it how to make it in C++. It call's paint method only once.

Any suggestions?

Source code:
myimage.h

```
#ifndef MYIMAGE_H
#define MYIMAGE_H

#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QPainter>

class MyImage : public QQuickPaintedItem
   {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyImage(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
    void paint(QPainter* painter) override;

signals:    


public slots:   
    };

#endif // MYIMAGE_H
```

myimage.cpp

```
#include "layerimage.h"

MyImage::MyImage(QQuickItem *parent) : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
    setImplicitWidth(600);
    setImplicitHeight(600);
}

void MyImage::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QImage firstImage("e:/image1.png");
    QImage secondImage("e:/image2.png");

    secondImage = secondImage.mirrored(false, true);

    firstImage = firstImage.scaled(width(), height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    secondImage = secondImage.scaled(width(), height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    painter->drawImage(0,0, firstImage);
    painter->setOpacity(0.5);
    painter->drawImage(0,0, secondImage);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "myimage.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<MyImage>("CustomImage", 1, 0 , "MyImage");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import CustomImage 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 900
    height: 900
    minimumWidth: 900
    minimumHeight: 480
    title: qsTr("Checker")

    Rectangle
    {
        id: image
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "red"
        anchors
        {
            margins: 20
            centerIn: parent
            fill: parent
        }
        MyImage
        {
            anchors
            {
                centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "changing its own size"? The `paint()` function is automatically called when the item is resized, last time I checked.

Comment: well, when i inserted qDebug << "Painting!" into the paint method it was printed only once - at the begining.
if i'll change application window width or height it'll be silent like a fish.

Comment: And please do NOT load an image from disk at every repaint!

Answer (score 0):

Okey. I have found a solution. Seems like i need make MyImage element anchors.fill: parent. Or set width and height equal to parents size. 
After that it will call paint every resize window moment!